# How to set-up a Gnu/Linux distro for kids?

Tags: linux, software-rec, distributions, gnu

I will have to repair a computer, which will be used by kids (9-12 years).
This computer had Vista, but I will install a Gnu/Linux distro, for security/pedagogic reasons.

I just come here to ask if you have any tips to secure the thing, and if you have some applications to recommend; like browser-filter, kid-protection, parental-control, encyclopedia, pedagogic tools...

I have also looked for a child-friendly Gnu/Linux OS, but they seems kind of old, with not so nice GUI, that is maybe fit for a 5 year old, but not for older children familiar with OSX, Windows, Netflix and other HD entertainment.

They will need something more "adult" than DoudouLinux.

I'm still looking for a kids-specific Gnu/Linux, but what I am inclined to do is to set-up Debian, with some specific application like parental-control, etc.

Comment: Have you checked out Debian Edu?

Comment: If you choose an education distro that is a sub project of a larger one. Then you can install multiple desktops: e.g. one for the very young, one for beginners, one for power users etc.

Comment: visit https://www.edubuntu.org/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) [Edubuntu](https://www.edubuntu.org/),It is a part of Ubuntu Project.

2) [Qimo](http://www.qimo4kids.com/), It is also based on Ubuntu.

3) [Ubermix](http://www.ubermix.org/about.html), It's almost same as Ubuntu but It has applications which are for kids.

For Kid-Safety applications, There Is 'Parental Control' which is help you control your web-browser.

There are a lot of time time organizer applications for to get control how much time PC going to open.

Comment: I'm looking forward to try Edubuntu on a VM, just to test it out.
But, what do you think about skolelinux ? Does this distro fit to a "only one desktop usage" ?
I will try them both btw. Thanks

Comment: Skolelinux seems pretty fine but I never tried it, so I cannot say any spesific thing about it.